# Xamarin how to draw a chart using AChartEngine

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-intent, charts

I want to draw a chart. I found [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/) library, but it has demos only in java.

I did Main.axml using [demo](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine) as example. If I understood it correclty, *LinearLayour* will be the chart. When I started to implement the main code, I stumbled upon a problem:

`private IDemoChart[] mCharts = new IDemoChart[]` where `IDemoChart` interface.

But C# can't make an object from an interface.

Also, I don't know how to assign this chart to the `LinearLayout`

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add_values"
        android:id="@+id/topText" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="71.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/xValue"
            android:layout_marginRight="35.5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="y"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="83.0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/yValue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="51.5dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_series"
            android:text="new_series"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using AChartEngine.Charts;
using AChartEngine.Models;
using AChartEngine.Renderers;
using AChartEngine;

namespace ChartsAChartEngine
{
    [Activity(Label = "ChartsAChartEngine", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            TextView topText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.topText);
            EditText editTextX = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.xValue);
            EditText editTextY = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.yValue);
            Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.add);
            LinearLayout linearLayoutChart = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.chart);
            var dataSetXY = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            var series = new XYSeries("test");
            series.Add(0, 0);
            series.Add(1, 1);
            series.Add(2, 2);
            dataSetXY.AddSeries(series);
            var renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            var lineChart = new LineChart(dataSetXY,renderer);
            var view = new GraphicalView(this,lineChart); // how to draw this?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently AChartsEngine is made specifically for Android Apps in Java language, so it won't work well in Xamarin C#...

I suggest you to use another plugin, the best I've found so far is this one:

https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/

it's great and works for Android, iOS and Windows Phone, all made for c# and Xamarin
***---EDIT---***
The NuGet Package to use it:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microcharts.Forms/0.8.3-pre  (pre-release)
OR
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microcharts.Forms/0.7.1

it will need another plugin also: SkiaSharp, but it will install automatically when Microcharts are installed. 
It's important to have an up to date version of Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: i download https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts, but i can't run this project `Microcharts-master\Sources\Microcharts.Samples.Forms\MainPage.cs(9,25,9,44): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: normally it can be solved just cleaning and recompiling the entire project... but also, you need to check if the nuGet packages are correctly downloaded to the project.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microcharts.Forms/ 
I didn't tested the project from gitHub, I just instaled the packeges and then used it in my project using the examples